# How to get seaborn barplot to plot using an array

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I have an array of two peak widths. One for an initial read of a photoluminescence spectra and one that is the last read.

The array looks like this:

```
array([[12.91895903, 13.4987366 ],
   [12.80932225, 13.48703181],
   [13.31956175, 13.84200578],
   [12.75569909, 13.40102423],
   [13.0540267 , 13.49630721],
   [12.99562842, 13.81240577],
   [12.3739669 , 13.50472869],
   [12.59581501, 13.59014109],
   [12.63003447, 13.62653901],
   [12.69311443, 13.43675767],
   [14.13148875, 13.90222385],
   [14.25998466, 14.1033694 ],
   [15.05208333, 14.84765915],
   [14.43515386, 14.04508814],
   [14.65407438, 14.60280042],
   [14.66398986, 14.51622903],
   [13.83106512, 13.78256313],
   [14.19863707, 13.96298736],
   [14.1713615 , 14.07543705],
   [13.83595496, 13.62599452],
   [12.3825998 , 12.70562171],
   [12.41156963, 12.88003495],
   [12.6777705 , 12.57068032],
   [12.53358095, 12.53534449],
   [13.45467719, 13.26144976],
   [12.78833045, 12.85806402],
   [12.60006425, 12.71363882],
   [12.88643467, 13.0602158 ],
   [13.23320967, 12.97156171],
   [12.86351657, 12.59229069],
   [14.74385343, 14.55740068],
   [15.00878816, 14.15872598],
   [14.58857873, 14.41833132],
   [14.92660875, 14.74147173],
   [15.12535649, 14.95838854],
   [14.64001146, 14.49185211],
   [14.82511105, 14.17740149],
   [15.12634785, 14.84858821],
   [14.34005113, 14.05463422],
   [14.15628504, 14.22486095],
   [12.3724133 , 12.58139608],
   [12.6060462 , 12.38097205],
   [12.90278338, 12.51676469],
   [13.76348633, 13.87927538],
   [14.71027281, 14.53496475],
   [14.40312148, 14.13345032],
   [13.7478055 , 13.80244484],
   [13.95752547, 14.05217398],
   [13.71435207, 13.82068027],
   [14.38300654, 14.02735273],
   [15.26673587, 14.53162147],
   [14.85648967, 14.37392304],
   [15.08822055, 14.72235331],
   [15.21932049, 13.80745798],
   [14.58129602, 14.10233792],
   [15.01609195, 13.99400871],
   [15.13918822, 14.17885891],
   [15.26248343, 14.16096096],
   [14.51957429, 13.88691796],
   [15.41818182, 15.15656029],
   [12.6553847 , 13.38708514],
   [13.13494664, 12.85261161],
   [13.70420034, 13.59193989],
   [15.3673978 , 14.55661419],
   [15.35887749, 14.83222518],
   [14.6031553 , 14.43384645],
   [15.09809249, 14.67672868],
   [14.71077586, 14.03549349],
   [17.78779038, 16.91968642],
   [14.18220261, 13.96151245],
   [15.65687646, 15.01666667],
   [15.50157895, 15.31943179],
   [15.36605773, 15.12444836],
   [15.515625  , 15.02318195],
   [15.99393939, 15.71333964],
   [15.82986111, 14.83928571],
   [16.38146168, 15.81002331],
   [17.21031746, 16.58461538],
   [15.64144737, 15.65714286],
   [17.22619048, 16.07165816]])
```

I want to plot it using a barplot but I am having trouble since it keeps on telling me it must be 1 dimensional but I am having trouble splitting so it can be read.

I am sure this is simple, but I can't seem to get it.

```
y= peaks_width[:,0]
x= peaks_width[0,:]
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.barplot(x, y)
```

Comment: Check out the numpy indexing guide: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html

Your issue is that x should be `peaks_width[:, 1]`